# Fragment Transaction Hide after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, hide, fragment

I want that my application adds all the fragments when my activity is created ( onCreate) and remove it when my activity die ( onDestroy) but if i try to do this, when i rotate my device my app crash and Log tells me:

java.lang.IllegalStateExceptiom : can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

There's a way to do what i wanna do?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing them in `onPause` before you call `super.onPause()`. You will then find that the fragments disappear when you rotate the device. So if you then also move the adding of the Fragments from `onCreate` into `onResume` you should be ok.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle